# Как сделать дополнительные кнопки на окне?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как сделать дополнительные кнопки на окне, помимо 3 основных (свернуть, развернуть, закрыть) на C#?

Comment: а вы [гуглили][1] ?


  [1]: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/buttons/CCaptionButton.aspx

Comment: А вы смотрели, что сами нагуглили? Я не разбираюсь в C++ да и в C# ели как

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала, судя по всему, без использования Win32 не обойтись. (Или третьесторонней библиотеки, к-ая за вас использует Win32).

[Вот здесь я нашел более менее ответ.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841180/how-to-add-an-extra-button-to-the-windows-title-bar)
[Пример оттуда же.](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=5bb13275dc6b8248&sc=documents&uc=1&id=5BB13275DC6B8248%21162#) (попробовал, правда работает)

Далее перевожу вариант, совместимый с Аэро (как наиболее актуальный):

Это решение основано на Win32-примере по этой ссылке: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb688195(VS.85).aspx

В принципе, нужно сделать следующее:

- Расширить клиентскую область окна так, чтобы она покрывала весь Frame. Для этого нужно перехватить WM_NCCALCSIZE-сообщение и вернуть 0. Так не-клиентская область станет нулевого размера, что значит, что клиентская будет покрывать все окно.
- Расширить Frame до размеров клиентской области, используя [DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969512(VS.85).aspx). Это скажет ОС рисовать Frame над клиентской областью.

Вышеописанные шаги дают вам окна со стандартным стеклянным оформлением, исключая иконку окна и заголовок. Кнопки свернуть, развернуть и закрыть будут продолжать рисоваться и работать. Что не будет работать, так это перетаскивание и изменение размеров окна, потому что фрейма теперь нет, а клиентская область покрывает все окно.

Теперь можно рисовать на окне как обычно. Можно даже поместить контролы в заголовок.

Осталось только перехватывать WM_NCHITTEST-сообщения, брать из них информацию о положении курсора мыши и возвращать информацию о том, в какой части окна он находится. Например, если вернуть HT_CAPTION, то окно будет работать так, как будто курсор находится на заголовке, и будет позволять перетаскивать окно и т.д. С этой функцией получится сделать полнофункциональное окно с кастомным фреймом.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ :)